# failed-to-start-process-automatic-reporting-is-enabled

Tags: nvidia, 22.04

I have Ubuntu 22.04.  I changed the system driver to "Using NVIDIA driver metapackage" and now I restarted the system and it gave this error:

```
failed-to-start-process-automatic-reporting-is-enabled
```

I entered shell recovery and typed these commands:

- `mount -o remount,rw /`
- `mount --all command`
- `systemctl disable apport.service`

The above error disappeared during reboot, but the system still does not load.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi Amir! Can you tell us, what graphics card you are using? If you don't know, you can run `lspci | grep VGA`. Please edit your question and add that info.